# Angular merge map for one after another http calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

The `getDetails()` method returns an `Details[]` and with that array and there is a name property which I am passing to another http call

```
Details {
    name: String;
```

Details

```
 getDetails()
     return this.https.get("/someValue") //this return Details[] from here I have to take  name property
```

return

```
{name : hello}
```

Information

```
 getInformations(name:string) {
    return this.https.get("/anotherValue"+"?"+ name)
 }
```

I am trying to first call `getDetails()` and pass the name property to

```
Information{
  Hieght:string
  age:string
}

getInformations()
this.getDetails().pipe(mergeMap(x => 
 this.getInformations(x.name)).subscribe((inforamtionResults:Information[])=>{
  console.log("Checking Informations"+inforamtionResults.length)
```

return

```
 {height:160,
   age: 23
   }
```

This is not working as x value is an array. How do iterate the array and pass the array property as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need to iterate each <strike>`this.getInformations(x.id)`</strike> `Details`. You can do this by simply using `Array.map()`. However, `mergeMap` wants one observable, but what we have is an array of observables. Thankfully, we can combine those array of observable to just one observable using rxjs' `forkJoin`.

```js
this.getDetails()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((details) =>
      forkJoin(details.map((x) => this.getInformations(x.id)))
    )
  )
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Here is a [sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-keller-w4cr9?file=/src/app/app.component.ts). I've used a different API but the implementation is similar.

Comment: When dealing with rxjs, this [operator decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) helps me a lot so I'll just put this here.

Comment: For x I am getting  double array vaue x[][]

Comment: `forkJoin` isn't deprecated as said [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) (I am using `rxjs 6.5.4`). Can you update your question to also show the structure of your data that you'll receive from `getDetails()` and `getInformations()`?

Comment: I have updated the question...Can you please have a look.I dont want to iterate each  this.getInformations(x.id).Just want to do a sequence HTTP calls first retriev get details and take the name propert from there and then pass the same property to the another call getInformation(x.id)

Comment: Is `getDetails()` really returning an array? But in your question, you said that it returns `{name: "hello"}` which is clearly not an array. Also, `Details` does not have an `id` property, but you tried to access it here: `this.getInformations(x.id)`. I am more confused now. Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or a working demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can help you better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221415/discussion-between-subham-and-blackraspberryyy).

Answer (score -1):

You need to try Like this.

```
 getDetails() {
    return this.http.get("/someValue")
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((x) => {
          return this.getInformations(x.id)
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Why you are using response??